# View with parameters in Sybase SQL Anywhere

Tags: t-sql, view, sybase, sybase-sql-anywhere

A view with `Sybase` engine cannot take parameters. **Is there a way to do this?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Solution is to create procedure with use of dynamic query:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE view_with_parms( in str1 varchar(255), in str2 varchar(50) ) 
RESULT(
  myID integer,
  someName varchar(255))
BEGIN
    EXECUTE ( 'select myID, someName from ' || str1 || ' order by ' || str2 || ' asc' );
END
```

then:

```
select * from view_with_parms('test_table','myID');
```

Tested with:

- SQL Anywhere 9
- SQL Anywhere 12